# Cannot Call A Method On A Null (Excel WorkSheet)

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm currently trying to grab a specific worksheet from an Excel file in PowerShell and I'm receiving the error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression".  PowerShell picks up the workbook and even that the property `Worksheet` exists, yet it does not recognize `item(1)`.

```
$excel = "C:\budget.xlsx"
$ex = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$ex.Visible = $true
$wb = $ex.Workbooks.Open($excel)
$ws = $wb.Worksheets.item(1) # This line errors
```

When accessing Excel worksheets, this is the syntax (for instance, [see this code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/451744/Extract-worksheets-from-Excel-into-separate-files), and this is just one of many examples).  Is there something else that needs to be loaded in order to do this?  After searching the 'net, I can't find anyone else loading or using another syntax.

Comment: Which line is giving the error?

Comment: `$ws = $wb.Worksheets.item(1)`

Comment: If you run the script as far as the `$wb = ...` line, then check value of `$wb`, what is result?

Comment: @andyb If I comment out the line `$wb = $ex.Workbooks.Open($excel)`, it launches a Read-Only version of the Excel workbook.  Got it: I have to run PowerShell as administrator in order to access worksheet items.  Thanks!

Comment: I ran the script without elevating and had no issues with it. I'm guessing then that the problem was related to permissions on the file itself.

Comment: I'm very interested by any possible solution as I'm encountering the same issue even though the file I'm opening is not in read-only and powershell is running as administrator..