# Unable to access worksheet layer of Excel through powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, worksheet

I have been trying to write a script in windows powershell that takes a value from a worksheet cell and then changes the value of a slicer with it. However, the part that is stumping me should be the simplest. Any time I try to access the worksheet layer in Microsoft Excel, I am given an error which states: "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."

I have tried several ways, declaring an active worksheet, adding worksheets, trying to reference existing worksheets, any attempt to access worksheets gives this same error. Because of this I can only code up to 6 lines of code before it fails. here is an example of code which fails at the last line.

```
$FilePath = "C:\Users\mudkip\desktop\slicer\TestMe.xlsx"    
$SheetName = "Sheet1"     
$objExcel = New-Object -Com "Excel.Application"    
$objExcel.Visible = $true    
$workbook = $ObjExcel.workbooks.open($filePath)    
$worksheet = $workbook.sheets.item($SheetName)
```

Other lines such as

```
  $WorksheetA = $Workbook.Worksheets.add()
```

also cause the same null valued expression failure. If anyone has any clue what could cause the worksheet layer to exhibit this strange resistance to any sort of interaction I would love to hear it, I'm totally stumped as to why copy pasted code that works for so many other users fails when I try to use it. 
I am using Windows 8.1 Enterprise, 
Microsoft Excel version 2013. 
Running powershell though the Windows PowerShell ISE.

Comment: If you open this file manually (i.e., by double-clicking it) does it raise any warnings, alerts, etc.?  Perhaps it is prompting you for security, or to update links, etc.  Are you sure `"Sheet1"` exists? (Try referencing it by index instead?) Or is the Workbook protected?  You generally can't add sheets on a Protected file.

Comment: These are all good things to check, unfortunately, none of them have panned out for me. Sheet1 does indeed exists, and opening the worksheet both normally (double-click) and through isolated powershell lines works fine. The sheet is not protected, although it does say that data-connections have been disabled. I was under the impression that this was for sql-server/ cube connections though, and enabling them doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: If you echo `$workbook | get-member` does it display `sheets` and/or `worksheets` as available members of the Workbook class?

Comment: also curious what happens if you do a `foreach ($worksheet in $workbook){$worksheet.name}` If it prints out the sheet name, try adding a `break` to exit loop when the sheet is found?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22683931/cannot-call-a-method-on-a-null-excel-worksheet) help? Seems to be same problem, and same code construct, user resolved it by running PS as Administrator. Another user suggested problem if the file is open in Read Only mode, so if that is the case you may want to check for orphaned instance of Excel in Task Manager, which may be holding that file "open".

Comment: I managed to fix the problem, unfortunately I'm still not sure what caused it in the first place. I just re-installed Microsoft Excel and all of a sudden I'm not getting anymore worksheet errors. Tech support level: try turning it off and on again ;-_- Thanks for all your help David!

Answer (score 1):

Re-installed Microsoft Excel, problem disappeared.